# Hibernate auto delete first child in @ManyToOne and @OneToManyAssociation

Tags: java, hibernate, transactional

We use springboot2 with hibernate 5.2.17.
We have strange behavior of hibernate with @ManyToOne and @OneToMany

Pseudo-code

```
 public class OwningSide {

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "owningSide")
   @MapKey(name = "keyColumn")
   @SortNatural
   private SortedMap<Long, NonOwningSide> nonOwningSideMap= new TreeMap<>(naturalOrder());       
}

public class NonOwningSide {

 @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = OwningSide.class)
 @JoinColumn(name = "owningSide_id")
 private OwningSide owningSide;
}

public class Service{

    @Transactional
   public void removeByKey(OwnerSide ownerSide)
    {
 SortedMap<Long, NonOwningSide> nonOwningSideMap=ownerSide.getNonOwningSideMap();
             nonOwningSideMap.remove(3);

     }
}
```

After return, hibernate, delete 2 rows.

```
Hibernate: delete from schema.NonOwnerTable where id=? and version=?
Hibernate: delete from schema.NonOwnerTable where id=? and version=?
```

It remove my row, that I want to delete and first row in map. Always first row.

If I remove Cascade.ALL from @ManyToOne problem is resolving.
But, I dont't understand, why hibernate delete first row with Cascade.ALL